# Specify source IP address while using go-ping library

Tags: go

I am using go-ping library (https://github.com/sparrc/go-ping) in my code, Is there any way so that I can specify source IP address from which to measure RTT just like we have -s option in using ping.

Here is my code. I want to specify source IP address to measure all these values. Has anyone done this before?

```
timeout := time.Second * 1000
interval := time.Second
count := 5
host := p.ipAddr
pinger, cmdErr := ping.NewPinger(host)

if cmdErr != nil {
    glog.Error("Failed to ping " + p.ipAddr)
    err = cmdErr
    return
}

pinger.Count = count
pinger.Interval = interval
pinger.Timeout = timeout
pinger.SetPrivileged(false)
pinger.Run()
stats := pinger.Statistics()
latency = float64(stats.AvgRtt) / float64(time.Millisecond)
jitter = float64(stats.StdDevRtt) / float64(time.Millisecond)
packetLoss = stats.PacketLoss
```

Comment: there is " source string "field in Pinger struct but how do I set it? I can not see any method to set it.

Comment: If the package doesn't expose that field, you either need to modify the package or use a different one.